# Is it possible to rotate the frame while decoding a video with ffmpeg c++ api based on the metadata info?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Currently, I got the rotation info by:

`av_dict_get(videoStream->metadata, "rotate", NULL, AV_DICT_MATCH_CASE);`

Now, how can I apply this rotation value while I decoding the video?

I decode the frame with:`avcodec_send_packet()` and `avcodec_receive_frame()`, then covert the pixel format and scale the frame with `sws_scale()`.

Comment: Usually a rotate filter will do this. But it's not clear what you need by "applying this rotation value".

Comment: @halfelf I mean rotate the frame by certain degree (90, 180 or 270)

Comment: In that case, I guess filter example in ffmpeg source and rotate filter document could be a good start.

Comment: @halfelf Yeah, filters like 'transpose', 'hflip', 'vflip' will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a filter graph and a transpose or hflip filter. Swscale won’t do it.